# Unable to install Robot framework with python 2.7.15

Tags: python

i installed Eclipse 2018-09 and python 2.7.15
then i tried to install robot framework with python using command pip install robotframwork

it returns:

```
Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.17134.1006]
(c) Microsoft Corporation, 2018. Tous droits réservés.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python --version
Python 2.7.15

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install robotframework
Collecting robotframework
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000044D0A90>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/robotframework/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000044D0940>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/robotframework/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000044D0C50>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/robotframework/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000044D0FD0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/robotframework/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000044D06D8>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/robotframework/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for robotframework

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: error shows that it tries few times connect with server but it has problem so it can be only problem with internet. Try next day. OR check if you have connection to internet.

Comment: So after sometimes it says : ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for robotframework

Comment: it can't find satisfying version because it can't connect to server.

Comment: You are right Furas, i'm checking this. thank you